# Expected Unqualified-Id in Header C++

Tags: c++, header

I am trying to make a simple program with SFML. So far I have a main file and a file to open the window, and that file's header. Thing is, I've had a problem with the header:

```
#ifndef Window.hpp
#define Window.hpp

Window();
int Loop();

#endif
```

I get this error:

C:...\Window.hpp|4|error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token|

The window file is:

```
#import <SFML/Window.hpp>
#import <iostream>

// This file needs to create and maintain the program's window, and change it's state.

class Window
{
sf::RenderWindow appWindow;
sf::Image charImage;
sf::Sprite charSpriteSheet;

public:
Window();
int Loop();
}

Window::Window()
{
appWindow.Create(sf::VideoMode( 800, 600, 32), "AI_Fighter");
if( !charImage.LoadFromFile("Bass.png") )
{
    cout << "Problem opening file 'Bass.png'";
}

charSpriteSheet.SetImage(charImage);
}

int Window::Loop()
{
    // Start game loop
while (appWindow.IsOpened())
{
    sf::Event evt;
    while (appWindow.GetEvent(evt))
    {
        // Window closed
        if (evt.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
            appWindow.Close();

        // Escape key pressed
        if ((evt.Type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (evt.Key.Code == sf::Key::Escape))
            appWindow.Close();
    }

    // Get elapsed time
    float ElapsedTime = appWindow.GetFrameTime();

    // Move the sprite
    if (appWindow.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Left))  charSpriteSheet.Move(-100 * ElapsedTime, 0);
    if (appWindow.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Right)) charSpriteSheet.Move( 100 * ElapsedTime, 0);
    if (appWindow.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Up))    charSpriteSheet.Move(0, -100 * ElapsedTime);
    if (appWindow.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Down))  charSpriteSheet.Move(0,  100 * ElapsedTime);

    // Rotate the sprite
    if (appWindow.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Add))      charSpriteSheet.Rotate(-100 * ElapsedTime);
    if (appWindow.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Subtract)) charSpriteSheet.Rotate( 100 * ElapsedTime);

    // Clear the screen (fill it with black color)
    appWindow.Clear(sf::Color( 0, 0, 0));

    appWindow.Draw(charSpriteSheet);

    // Display window contents on screen
    appWindow.Display();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think `.` are allowed in `#define` constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
#ifndef Window.hpp
#define Window.hpp
```

to

```
#ifndef Window_hpp
#define Window_hpp
```

Comment: Missing ";" to close the class before Window::Window().

Comment: Fixed that already... However I still get C:\...\Window.hpp|4|error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token|

Comment: 4. Nevermind however, I found out how to do a *proper* header and now it's working. Thanks for the help.